# Función o rutina para cambiar el color de los botones

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Lo que pretendo es cambiar el estado de los botones, es decir.

Tengo 8 botones cuando abro el Jframe entonces mantener resaltado el botón 1, y el resto de los botones de otro color.
Si presiono el botón dos entonces entonces resaltar este y mantener el resto de otro color.

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo botón por botón así:

```
if(this.btn1.isSelected()){
        this.btn1.setColorNormal(new Color(26,25,62));
        this.btn1.setColorHover(new Color(26,25,62));
        this.btn1.setColorPressed(new Color(26,25,62));

        this.btn2.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn2.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn2.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));

        this.btn3.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn3.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn3.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));

        this.btn4.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn4.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn4.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));

        this.btn5.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn5.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn5.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));

        this.btn6.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn6.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn6.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));

        this.btn7.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn7.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn7.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));

        this.btn8.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn8.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
        this.btn8.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));
    }else{
        this.btn1.setColorNormal(new Color(26,25,62));
        this.btn1.setColorHover(new Color(26,25,62));
        this.btn1.setColorPressed(new Color(26,25,62));
    }
}
```

Existe alguna función en NetBeans de optimizar esto sin escribir en cada botón tanto código?

DS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que los botones son de tipo `JButton`, podrías crear 3 métodos para que no repitas tanto código:

```
private void highlightButton(JButton btn) {
    btn.setColorNormal(new Color(26,25,62));
    btn.setColorHover(new Color(26,25,62));
    btn.setColorPressed(new Color(26,25,62));
}

private void resetButton(JButton btn) {
    btn.setColorNormal(new Color(30,30,46));
    btn.setColorHover(new Color(30,30,46));
    btn.setColorPressed(new Color(30,30,46));
}

private void resetAllButtons() {
    resetButton(this.btn1);
    resetButton(this.btn2);
    resetButton(this.btn3);
    resetButton(this.btn4);
    resetButton(this.btn5);
    resetButton(this.btn6);
    resetButton(this.btn7);
    resetButton(this.btn8);
}
```

Y ahora todo lo que tienes que hacer es llamar a los métodos `resetAllButtons` y `highlightButton` dentro del bloque de código que responde al evento del clic de cada botón. Por ejemplo para el botón 1 y 2 sería así:

```
btn1.addActionListener(e -> {
    resetAllButtons();
    highlightButton(btn1);
});

btn2.addActionListener(e -> {
    resetAllButtons();
    highlightButton(btn2);
});
```

Y si también te molesta repetir tanto ese código del evento puedes meter los botones en una lista y luego recorrerla añadiendo el evento a cada botón en lugar de poner el código del evento uno por uno:

```
//Variable miembro de la clase
private List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.btn1, this.btn2, this.btn3, this.btn4, this.btn5, this.btn6, this.btn7, this.btn8));
...
//Esto va dentro del constructor o donde sea que estés creando los botones
for(JButton button: buttons) {
    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        resetAllButtons();
        highlightButton(button);
    });
}
```

Y si los botones están en una lista entonces el método `resetAllButtons` pasaría a tener el siguiente código:

```
private void resetAllButtons() {
    for(JButton button: buttons)
        resetButton(button);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con tu métodos he solucionado mi problema. 
Gracias de nuevo y saludos.
DS